How to load big fixed data files into supabase from web front end?
I have to upload files regularly from a web frontend in React Next into Supabase. Files are in fix format (not csv). Each file contains more than 100 000 entries.
I tried many solutions

Uploading file in Supabase Storage  + Using Supabase Database function. It block after about 10 000 entries throwing a soft limit reached.

Using a rpc function. I didn't find a way to import data into a rpc function

Using pgloader (recommended by supabase for bulk import). It work really good but It's not easy to call pgloader from a web frontend !


